# Issue with React Server Components in Next.js - "ReactServerComponentsError"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm encountering an issue while using React Server Components in my Next.js project. The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
Failed to compile
./src\app\components\projects\slider.js
ReactServerComponentsError:

You're importing a component that needs useEffect. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.
,-[C:\Users\elias\Documents\Trabalhos\Repositorios\portifolio\src\app\components\projects\slider.js:1:1]
 1 | /* @jsxImportSource @react */
 2 | import Image from "next/image";
 3 | import "./slider.scss";
 4 | import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
   :                           ^^^^^^^^^
 5 | import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
 6 | import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css";
 7 | import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css";
   `----

Maybe one of these should be marked as a client entry with "use client":
  ./src\app\components\projects\slider.js
  ./src\app\page.tsx
```

Here's a summary of my code:

In the 'slider.js' file:

```
/* @jsxImportSource @react */
import Image from "next/image";
import "./slider.scss";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css";


let productsp = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product Number 1",
        brand: "Brand Name",
        url: "products-number-1",
        price: 100,
    },
];
var $ = require("jquery");
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
}

const OwlCarousel = dynamic(() => import("react-owl-carousel"), {
    ssr: false,
});

const Slider = () => {
    const options = {
        margin: 30,
        responsiveClass: true,
        nav: true,
        dots: true,
        autoplay: false,
        smartSpeed: 1000,
        navClass: ["owl-prev", "owl-next"],
        navText: [
            '',
            '',
        ],
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
            },
            400: {
                items: 1,
            },
            600: {
                items: 2,
            },
            700: {
                items: 3,
            },
            1000: {
                items: 4,
            },
        },
    };

    return (
        <div className="row no-gutters">
            <div
                className="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mt-3 pb-2 bg-white"
                id="owl-carousel-products"
            >
                <h3 className="text-center">
                    <span className="heading float-left w-100">Featured Products</span>
                </h3>
                <ul id="owl-carousel-ul" className="owl-carousel owl-loaded owl-drag">
                    <OwlCarousel
                        className="owl-theme"
                        loop
                        margin={4}
                        nav={true}
                        navText={[
                            '<img src="/images/Arrow_left.png" />',
                            '<img src="/images/Arrow_right.png" />',
                        ]}
                        dots={false}
                        animateIn={true}
                        {...options}
                    >
                        {productsp && productsp.length > 0
                            ? productsp.map((product) => {
                                return (
                                    <div
                                        id="featuredProducts"
                                        className="item float-left w-100"
                                        key={product.name}
                                    >
                                        <div className="productListing col-lg-5th col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <a href={product.url}>
                                                <a className="product float-left">
                                                    <span className="image text-center">
                                                        <Image
                                                            id={"img" + product.id}
                                                            src="images/product.jpg"
                                                            alt={product.name}
                                                            title={product.name}
                                                        />
                                                    </span>
                                                    <span className="w-100 text-center mt-1 ">
                                                        <h5 className="brand text-capitalize float-left">
                                                            {product.brand}
                                                        </h5>
                                                        <span className="name">{product.name}</span>
                                                        <strong className="itemPrice p-0">
                                                            Price: {product.price}
                                                        </strong>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })
                            : ""}
                    </OwlCarousel>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
);
};
export default Slider;
```

And in the 'page.tsx' file:

```
import { Experience } from './components/experience/experience'
import { Header } from './components/header/header'
import { Info } from './components/information/information'
import Slider from './components/projects/slider'


import "./styles/home.scss"
import { EmailIcon } from './components/icons/email-icon'
import { SocialBtns } from './components/social-btns/social-btns'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="container">
      <Header />
      <Experience />
      <Info />
      <div className="buttons">
        <SocialBtns />
        <a className="btn-primary" href="mailto:elias.souza.es609@gmail.com">
          contact me
          <EmailIcon />
        </a>
      </div>
      <Slider />
    </main>
  )
}`
```

I've already marked the parent component page.tsx with /* @jsxImportSource @react */, but I'm still getting this error related to the use of useEffect.

I suspect this might be due to my project not using Babel. Do I need to install and configure Babel to make React Server Components work in Next.js?```

Comment: To use `useEffect` or `useState` in NextJS you need to make it a client component and add athe first line of your file 'use client'.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#using-client-components-in-nextjs

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have `use client` as the first line of the file (Or as the first line of one of it's direct parent files. Take a look at the docs about this [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components) for more explanation.

So add it on the `slider.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

By default all NextJS components are server components which means you cannot use react hooks with it.

You also cannot assign event handlers to it.

What the above answer is suggesting is that you make your server component into a client component by adding the **use client** at the top of the file, then you can have all the usual rules of components including the use of hooks, event handlers, etcetera.